# Default value for entity backed Date field in Symfony2 Form Builder

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine, symfony-forms

Okay, I've got the FormType described below.  I use this Form class for both the create and edit forms.  I decided to set a default date (`from_date` and `to_date` below), using the `data` attribute in the options array.  This does a great job of setting the default date, in fact, too good a job.  It also overrides the existing date in the edit form, which is no good at all, really.

How do I set a real 'default' value, as opposed to an 'always' value?

```
<?php

namespace TechPeople\InvoiceBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;


class InvoiceType extends AbstractType
{
    private $user;

    public function __construct(SecurityContext $security_context)
    {
        $this->user = $security_context->getToken()->getUser();
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $lastMonth = new \DateTime();$lastMonth->modify('-1 month');
        $builder
            ->add('month', 'choice', array(
                'data' => $lastMonth->format('F'),
                'choices' => array(
                    "January" => "January",
                    "February" => "February",
                    "March" => "March",
                    "April" => "April",
                    "May" => "May",
                    "June" => "June",
                    "July" => "July",
                    "August" => "August",
                    "September" => "September",
                    "October" => "October",
                    "Novemeber" => "Novemeber",
                    "December" => "December",
                )
            ))
            ->add('year', null, array(
                'data' => $lastMonth->format('Y')
            ))
            ->add('from_date', 'date', array(
                 'label' => 'From',
                 'data' => new \DateTime(),
            ))
            ->add('to_date', 'date', array(
                 'label' => 'To',
                 //'data' => new \DateTime(),
            ))
            ->add('hours')
            ->add('expenses')
            ->add('expense_amount', 'money',
                array(
                    'required' => false,
                ))
            ->add('attachment', 'file',
                array(
                    'path'=>$options['data']->getAttachmentPath(),
                    'required' => false,
                )
            )
        ;
        if($this->user->hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')){
            $builder->add('vendor');
        }
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'TechPeople\InvoiceBundle\Entity\Invoice'
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'techpeople_invoicebundle_invoicetype';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set it on the entity, or any object you will use as form data, in the constructor or as default value !

```
class Invoice {

    private $month;
    private $year;
    private $from_date;
    private $to_date;
    //...

    public function __construct()
    {
        $lastMonth = new \DateTime('now - 1 month');
        $this->month = $lastMonth->format('F');
        $this->year = $lastMonth->format('Y');
        $this->from_date = new \DateTime;
        $this->to_date = new \DateTime;
        //...
    }
}
```

It will set up these 2 fields for a creation form, and in the case of a persisted entity, these values will be overriden by stored data at loading.

Comment: I swear I tried this last night and it didn't work.  However, this morning it most certainly does.  Maybe I just needed some sleep.  At any rate, thanks much.

Comment: Okay, I see why I'm confused.  When I tried this method before, I set the to_date like this: `$this->to_date = new \DateTime('2000-01-01');`  For some reason, no matter what I do, year shows up as 2008 in the create form. I tried changing the format and sticking in different years.  I don't actually need to set an explicit date like this, but the behavior is extremely bizarre.  What is the cosmic significance of the year 2008??

Comment: Also +1 for the vastly less clunky way of getting last month.  My version was nasty.

Comment: Out of curiosity, if the setting default values via the constructor works for the creation form, I guess that means an Invoice object is created when the creation form is rendered?  Is the object cached somewhere and updated and persisted when the form is submitted, or is the object destroyed and created again?

Comment: You go through the same controller for form rendering and form validation (i hope so), so your entity is created and initialized before rendering and before form rendering, so you handle same values for both steps.. But persistence is up to you, not "magically" processed by Symfony Form.

Comment: Yeah, looking at the Controller, I see what it's doing now.  I used the CRUD generator for the controller and views, so I didn't entirely know what magic was going on inside the box, so to speak.  Looking at it now, it's actually pretty straightforward.  Thanks.