# Sonata - Admin User enabled by default

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata-user-bundle

What I need to do is very simple:

Have the enabled checkbox checked by default at user creation time in the user admin edit form.

I have already extended SonataUserAdminBundle and done some successful modifications.

I tried to enable it in the extended User Entity

```php
class User extends AbstractedUser implements UserInterface
{
    #...
    protected $enabled = true;
    #...
}
```

But nothing changes.

How to enable a user by default at creation time ?

---

Also I tried to check it from the user admin class

```php
class UserAdmin extends BaseUserAdmin
{
    #...
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        #...
        $formMapper->with('Security')
            ->add('enabled', null
                , array('required' => false, 'checked' => 'yes'))
            ->end();
    }
    #...
}
```

But not a good idea because it will always come checked.

Comment: Use a constructor to set default values. Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14315685/default-value-for-entity-backed-date-field-in-symfony2-form-builder

Answer (score 1):

You can set it in the constructor of your entity:

```php
class User extends AbstractedUser implements UserInterface
{
    #...
    protected $enabled;
    #...
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->enabled = true;
    }
    #...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember to call the parent constructor and set your option after that:

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->enabled = true;
}
```